# Zuul url parameters to Solr Query parameters

Tags: solr, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to rewrite request with zuul and forward them to an old solr server.

My application.yml looks like this:

```
zuul:
  prefix: /api/v1
  routes:
    peoples:
      path: path: /peoples/**
      url: http://solr/api/select?
```

So far the `/people` route is working fine, i get the incoming request, pass the correct parameters to the request via a Zuulfilter and forward to solr. The redirected request looks:

`http://sorl/api/select?q=*&wt=json&indent=true&collection=MyCollection&fl=Filter1,Filter2,Filter3,Filter4&rows=10`

I don't understand how i can define a new route like : `peoples/{id}`. 
I need to pass the {id} route to another ZuulFilter and append it to `com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext.getCurrentContext().setRequestQueryParams()`

Am i missing something in Zuul or is it just no possible to get a param from the requestcontext, and transform it to a query param ?